# how to switch more 230v with arduino?

Tags: arduino-mega

i am working on a project automatic street lighting with arduino.i am done with the code and the circuit.i am able to switch the AC voltage in my house which is 230v,50hz with a 230v relay but when its comes to implementation there are 30 to 40 street lights are connected and the voltage is very high I think around 415 volts.what should I use to control that? need help

Comment: I'm quite surprised that you need to build a project with so high current/voltage/purpose around a coarse Arduino, are you sure of that ? Regarding the loads to switch, a relay is the simplest solution, but according the load type it could possibly have a huge current peak at turn on which will damage very quickly the relay if it's not intended to handle it, think carefully about it !

Comment: What is the current per light? Say it's 5 amps per light. For 40 lights you'd need a >415V (430V would be better) relay rated for >200A. (It would be a good idea to get a relay that can handle a little more than your peak power. So if your load is 200A, get a relay that can handle 20% more, or 240A.) That would be a heavy duty industrial relay, and not something you're going to find from a consumer electronics outlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a relay that can handle minimum 415 volts (and keep some reserve).

Also take the current/amperage into account (possibly use multiple relays).

Comment: I thaught that but I was unable to get 415v relay!

Comment: See e.g. https://nl.mouser.com/Electromechanical/Relays/General-Purpose-Relays/_/N-5g36 ... the list goes to 480 VAC. Tip: I wouldn't buy such high voltage items from ebay or aliexpress.

Comment: Thanks.actually I am computer science student I don't know which one to buy exactly so could help me with that! please

Comment: Also make sure the relay can handle the current used by 40 lights.

Comment: @prajwalmegalamani I also studied software engineering / computer science ... There are mostly two important properties: voltage (make sure it's at least 415V, preferably more, like 480 VAC. And either use multiple relays, one per light, or one per several light or sum up the current used by all of them and see if there is a relay that can have that amperage. E.g. 40 lights * 1 A / light = 40 A. Use a relay that is e.g. minum 45 of 50 A to be sure.

Comment: To add some backround to help you choose: The voltage spec of a relay's contacts (not its coil!) is the maximum voltage that it can open (i.e., interrupt) without arcing across the contacts and damaging them. The current spec - again, of the contacts - is the maximum current the contacts can carry while closed, without overheating. (When they're open, of course, they won't be carrying any current).

Comment: I took a training course just to be certified to flip an ~ 415 V breaker and strongly recommend that you do not work with those voltages at the current draw of street lights without proper EE training and certification or at least working with someone who knows what they are doing. We are talking dangerous stuff, here.